# Openlayers WKT field, Openlayers Map Widget and background layer

Tags: drupal, openlayers

I'm using Openlayers map widget to enter an openlayers wkt field for a custom content type. Everything works fine.
The additional feature I'd like to achieve is to have another openlayers view (showing a map with geographical features from another content type) as a background layer while I'm editing a node.

To make an example:
- I have a content type, say "paths" with its own openlayers wkt field and an openlayers view with a map of all paths.
- I want to be able to add nodes of another content type, again with a cck field, for example "points", while having the "paths" view as a background.
This is useful for a better visual placements of features based on other information entered previously.

Is this possible out of the box with openlayers or any other module?

Thanks a lot for your time and for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

imho, you need to add 2 data layers.

http://mapbox.com/documentation/drupal-tutorial has a simple description on how to add a new data layer (plus some other very nice tips)